# Not able to create a foreign key; Relation " " does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a foreign key called 'user_id' for a 'transactions' table where the user_id references the 'user_accounts' table 'id' column. I keep getting an error when I execute the script that says:

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "user_accounts" does not exist
```

The table clearly exists as I have been populating the user_accounts table with data that can be viewed in dbeaver. I am using Postgres and I am aware that quotes/capitalization can really make things difficult but I have executed my entire script without capitalizing or using quotes on any of the table or column names. Although, I did capitalize some of my column data types and I am wondering if that is the issue here? If so, what direction should I take to get my foreign key to work?

My script:

```
create table if not exists user_accounts (
    id serial primary key,
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR(30),
    username VARCHAR(20),
    password VARCHAR(20),
    deposit INT,
    creditScore INT 
)

create table if not exists transactions (
    transaction_id serial primary key,
    user_id INT references user_accounts(id) not null,
    transaction_type VARCHAR(20),
    amount INT
)
```

Comment: This works in db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=423e0e02c4349f1a56f6dddd5195f12a.

Comment: I have very little experience with Postgres, but is the issue when you run all at once? What if you first create `user_accounts` and then `transactions`? And what if you add a semicolon after each command? And is `user_accounts.id` an `int`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah super confused why it's not working for me

Comment: @Andrew I created both tables separately and I've tried running the whole script at once. Still get the same error. I've also tried adding a semicolon and that didn't work either. ```user_accounts.id``` has a serial constraint. Would that be the root problem??

Comment: Did you triple check the spelling? I can only reproduce your issue if I, for example, rename the first table to something like `user_account`.

Comment: @jc223 reverify the table name in your database. Whether it is in small case by running `select * from user_accounts limit 1`. I doubt it is not in small case or spelling is different

Comment: @AkhileshMishra so when I reverified, it would not give me a result at all and said the ```relation user_accounts" does not exist```. Very weird because I am able to use this table in my application

Comment: So it is clear your table does not exist ...

Comment: @AkhileshMishra I understand why you say that but the table is listed in my schema and I am able to insert data into this table as we speak. Is there a certain setting I can check?

Comment: What is the schema of your table user_account is displayed in dbeaver? Is it `public`

Comment: I figured it out. I was in the wrong schema :) My apologies, long day! @AkhileshMishra Thank you so much